# Display icons in Lightning-tab along with labels in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

Can we display icons along with labels in lightning-tab in LWC. In Aura framework we can do using below code :

```
<lightning:tab >

 <aura:set attribute="label">
      First Tab
      <lightning:icon size="small" iconName="utility:success" />
</aura:set>
 Tab1 Content
</lightning:tab>
```

Similarly, is there any way to achieve the same in LWC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `icon-name` inside the `ightning-tab`.

```
<lightning-tab label="First Tab" icon-name={iconName}>
</lightning-tab>
```

```
export default class App extends LightningElement {

 iconName;

  connectedCallback() {
    this.iconName = "utility:success";
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the icon-name dynamically through javascript?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in js, I updated the answer.

Comment: It worked..! Thank you for your help..!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Klecool Can we specify the size of the icon